# Can't get data from React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following ReactJS code:

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({

      render: function(){

        var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment){

          return (
            <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>
              {comment.text}
            </Comment>

          );

        });

        return (
          <div className="commentList">
            {commentNodes}
          </div>
        );

      }

    });
```

And in CommentBox....

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({

      loadCommentFromServer: function() {

        $.ajax({
          url: this.props.url,
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {

            this.setState({
              data: data
            });

          }.bind(this),

          error: function(xhr, status, err) {

              console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());

        }.bind(this)

        });

      },

    },
    getInitialState: function() {

      return {
        data: []
      };

    },

    componentDidMount: function() {

      this.loadCommentFromServer();

      setInterval(this.loadCommentFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);

    },

    render: function() {

      return ( 
        <div className = "commentBox" >
            <h1> Comments </h1> 
            <CommentList data ={ this.state.data } />
            <CommentForm />
        </div>
      );

     }

});
```

In `getInitialState()`, I already assign value for data and in `CommentList` also add property data which get value from state.

When I try to run, I got this error:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in CommentList.

Comment: do you change the state on componentDidMount? Are you sure it fails on the first render? I don't see anything that can possible go wrong in the first render, getInitialState runs before the first render

Comment: Yes I did change the state on componentDicMount by loading data from server via ajax.

Comment: Your code works, take a look in here. https://jsfiddle.net/4vaq7mL7/1/ show me the code on componentDidMount

Comment: componentDidMount: function(){
    // this method called automatically by React after a component is rendered for the first time
    this.loadCommentFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  }

Comment: and here loadCommentFromServer():
oadCommentFromServer: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err){
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }

Comment: Edit the question with the complete code, I can't read that.

Comment: edit already, please check it again.

Comment: Maybe you get this error after you get response from server? Add console.log to ajax success function and check if "data" is an array.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you simply aren't getting the data you want back from the jQuery.ajax.

```
      success: function(data) {
        // before setting state, log here and find out what data is
        // it could need to be turned into JSON? data = data.toJSON();
        // or simply this to be safe
        data = data || [];

        this.setState({
          data: data
        });

      }
```

Comment: This or response data is not an array.